How to clean corrupted data of pallet-contracts?
our chain was live few years ago. We had integrated pallet-contracts. During runtime-upgrade, it seems we had missed the migration of pallet-contracts.
Now we have corrupted data in pallet-contracts. For ex: There is no data in CodeInfoOf storage. But there is data in PristineCode. Ideally both should be removed together according to this.
What is the best way to purge the state/storage of the contracts pallet so that we remove all instances of contracts along with the data that is associated with the currently deployed contracts instances?

if you don't care about the storage and don't want to recover it, then you could remove any storage related to Contracts pallet with RemovePallet. But note that this operation might not fit in one block weight depending on the type of your chain, so consider multi block migrations.
